# Grafana | is there a way to make a graph using Prometheus to show cpu_usage for each pod per node in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm new to Promql and I'm trying to make a graph that shows cpu_usage by each pod in a node, I've tried this one:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name, node)
```

But it shows the usage by all the pods for all the nods

Comment: In short, you need to create a dashboard variable that'll query possible `node` labels: `label_values(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total, node)`. Then add `,node="$VARIABLE_NAME"` after your `image!=""` selector.

Comment: Yet it does the same thing it shows all the pods for all the nodes, it doesn't specify the pods for each node